# Generate labels and textboxes for each column in a db

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I want to generate 1 label and 1 textbox per column in a table. How would I do this? I am thinking it would be some statement that says for each column, add a label and textbox to the page. Also I would like each label and textbox to be named based on the name of the column.

This is how I am connecting to the DB. I am using Visual Studio and C#.

```
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionNameHere"].ConnectionString))
        {
            sqlConn2.Open();

            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand())
            {
                sqlCmd2.Connection = sqlConn2;
                sqlCmd2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                sqlCmd2.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS mWHERE table_name = 'registrants');
                sqlCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                using (SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd2.ExecuteReader())
                {
                  //Some code here?
                }



                sqlConn2.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What ASP.NET technology are you using, Web Forms or MVC?   Once this is answered there will be many more followup questions, so please try to provide as much detail upfront.

Comment: Okay, I will provide whatever is needed. I am using Web Forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ASP.NET Repeater](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater(v=vs.85).aspx) Control is an ideal solution for your problem, you can simply define a template (for label & textbox in your case) and it will bind them accordingly.

Define a repeater control like this:-

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MyColumn") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="textTest" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then, Change your query like this:-

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("MyColumn", typeof(string));
//Your rest code (connection object and all)
sqlCmd2.CommandText = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME  AS MyColumn
                       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                       WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName";
sqlCmd2.Parameters.Add("@TableName",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "registrants";
sqlConn2.Open();
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
       DataRow tableRow = table.NewRow();
       tableRow["MyColumn"] = reader["MyColumn"].ToString();
       table.Rows.Add(tableRow);
     }
     Repeater1.DataSource = table;
     Repeater1.DataBind();
}
```

Also, please note you should not use `ExecuteNonQuery` it is mainly used for DML operations. Using `ExecuteReader` will do the task.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. I didn't know there was a Repeater control. Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid Web Forms and move to [MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) if at all possible.  If not, it is not the end of the world, but you are living in the dark ages.  Also, never, ever, ever use inline SQL.  Either switch to an ORM like [EF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) or [Insight.Database](https://github.com/jonwagner/Insight.Database), or use stored procedures and parameterized ADO.NET calls.

Now that we have that out of the way.

It is simple really, you will need to do some reading to fully grasp how to bind your dataset or datatable to the web forms web controls.  The datagrid is probably your best bet.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa728895(v=vs.71).aspx
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anjudidi/example-of-datagrid-in-Asp-Net/

Both of the links above detail the binding aspects and explain how to correctly use them.  Again, if this can be avoided that it certainly what I would suggest.

Also, your ADO.NET calls will populate either a DataTable or a DataSet and then pass that to the Form for loading/binding.

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConn2 = new sqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionNameHere"].ConnectionString))
{
    sqlConn2.Open();

    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand())
    {
        sqlCmd2.Connection = sqlConn2;
        sqlCmd2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        sqlCmd2.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS mWHERE table_name = 'registrants');
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dataTable);            
        sqlConn2.Close();

        return dataTable;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Yeah I have to learn the better standards. I will definitely try to fix this in my code.

Comment: Please mark my answer appropriately if you feel it was correct.